# How to use Android classes in JVM?

Tags: java, android, jvm, robolectric, stub

I want to build a layout hierachy of Viewgroups and Views in a normal Java program and then send it to an android device. Since this is no test I can't use robolectric or other android test suites.
Are there non-stub versions of said android-layout-elements, that I can integrate in a JVM/server?

Comment: If you send an entire ui part to the android device, why don't you use html for that part?

Comment: Layout is made in XML, so this is just a string. No need for stubs.

Comment: I'm not using xml since the layout needs to be dynamic, meaning that I get layoutchanges through that same procedure at runtime and I can't inflate xmls after compiling when I'm not mistaken.